# Ajax Request Works Fine, Javascript Does Not

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am looking for a solution to a problem I am having with this request.

```
function getProfile() {
if (str = "") {
document.getElementById("welcomebar").innerHTML = "";
return;
} else {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("welcomebar").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/login.php?user="+document.getElementById("username").value, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

That is my ajax code, and this is my php file which is a separate file.

```
<?php

$servername = "";
$user = "";
$pw = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pw, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Could not connect to the server.");
}

$someone = $_GET["user"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_row='$someone'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "Welcome, " . $row["some_row"]. "<span id='date'></span>
<script>
var date = new Date();
var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
</script>
";
}
} else {
echo "Error";
}

?>
```

The ajax request is sending and receiving. When I log in as myself, the information I want it to display is being displayed properly. However, the java script code in the php file is not working when it is being received by the request. [picture of the view source window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0GMV.png)

Comment: If I were to use the php file as a php page with the post method it would work fine. It acts as if the javascript belongs to the page and the script works in that case.

Comment: that is correct behaviour. script tags added to the DOM using innerHTML are not executed

Comment: I'm assuming I'd have to actually create a javascript that reads the date into the id="date" element after the request is finalized? Yes, and it worked perfec

Comment: That's one solution

Comment: Another would be jquery?

Comment: yeah, jquery does the heavy lifting for you

Comment: Sorry, my post was cut off... I did that and it worked just fine. (I created the additional javascript).